# Mysql where between and equal to?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql function

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE BETWEEN '2011-01-03' AND '2011-01-01' AND `email`='sarah@sarah.com' AND `city`='New York' AND `location`='New York' AND `date` GROUP BY action
```

However I can't seem to get it working, it works if I take out the BETWEEN '2011-01-03' AND '2011-01-01' but not with it in, how can I make this function work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
WHERE BETWEEN '2011-01-03' AND '2011-01-01'
```

needs a column name to be compared. Is it the `date` column?

Then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `stats`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-03'
AND `email`='sarah@sarah.com'
AND `city`='New York'
AND `location`='New York'
GROUP BY action
```

Comment: +1 - looks like his query was squiffed. i've got a feeling the query was being dynamically created and the logic is awry there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

add the name of date field and

then

change the order

```
date  BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-03'
```

first the earliest day and after that the latest date

Answer (score 3):

Use

> (min<= expr AND expr<= max)

instead or use braces.

Answer (score 3):

Use column name before using between condition

Like As:

```
Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-03'
```

In your SQL You Forgot to put **"Date"** Field before **BETWEEN** Keyword

**Syntax**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: Use column name before Between keyword

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE COLUMN-NAME-HERE BETWEEN
```

Notice COLUMN-NAME-HERE you need the date field

Answer (score 2):

Hei you should have `WHERE date_column  BETWEEN '2011-01-03' AND '2011-01-01'` put the exact name of your column instead of `date_column` so you'll have

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `your_date_column` BETWEEN '2011-01-03' AND '2011-01-01' AND `email`='sarah@sarah.com' AND `city`='New York' AND `location`='New York' AND `date` GROUP BY action
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the time to the date:

```
$qAddDate = " AND (dCreated >= '".$_POST['datefrom']."' AND dCreated <= '".$_POST['dateto'].":23:59:59')";
```

Comment: This is a call for sql injection.