# How to select the record between the date range including the given date in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, between, date-range

I need to check the date in the range from_date and to_date.

Ex) Employee applies leave from 2012-11-08 to 2012-11-09, here I need to check 2012-11-08 with the date range includes the from_date and to_date.

Please suggest me to use the proper queries to get the records.

When I use Mysql BETWEEN, it checks the date in between range only and not including the from_date and to_date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232122/mysql-select-data-between-two-dates

Comment: Hope this post may be useful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594183/mysql-where-between-and-equal-to

Answer (score 0):

use a comparison operator:

WHERE  `from_date` >= '2012-11-08' AND `to_date` <= '2012-11-08'

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN in MySQL is inclusive, which means that 2012-11-08 falls within the range of 2012-11-08 - 2012-11-09. Your problem is probably the TIME part.

Try casting the database fields to date in your query and see what result you get, i.e.:

`SELECT x FROM y WHERE '2012-11-08' BETWEEN DATE(date_from) AND DATE(date_until)`